# How to get Use Attribute in XSOM Java library

Tags: java, xml, xsom

I am using [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/userguide.html) java library to parse XML Schema.
I don't know how to get the attribute "Use" for the Attribute Declaration.
Here is my code to get all attribute declarations for the CompleType

```
// To get ComplexType attributes
private static void getComplexAttributes(XSComplexType xsComplexType) {
    Collection<? extends XSAttributeUse> c = xsComplexType.getAttributeUses();
    Iterator<? extends XSAttributeUse> i = c.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        // i.next is attributeUse
        XSAttributeUse attributeUse = i.next();
        XSAttributeDecl attributeDecl = i.next().getDecl();
        System.out.println("Attributes for CoplexType: " + xsComplexType.getName());

        parseAttribute(attributeDecl, attributeUse);    
    }
}

// Get attribute info
private static void parseAttribute(XSAttributeDecl attributeDecl, XSAttributeUse attUse) { 
    System.out.println("Attribute Name: " + attributeDecl.getName());
    XSSimpleType xsAttributeType = attributeDecl.getType();
    System.out.println("Attribute Type: " + xsAttributeType.getName());
    if (attUse.isRequired())
        System.out.println("Use: Required");
    else
        System.out.println("Use: Optional");
    System.out.println("Fixed: " + attributeDecl.getFixedValue());
    System.out.println("Default: " + attributeDecl.getDefaultValue());
}
```

And I get this error:
java.util.NoSuchElementException

Pointing to the line

```
XSAttributeDecl attributeDecl = i.next().getDecl();
```

Can anyone help? do I miss anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem thanks

the right code here:

```
// To get ComplexType attributes
private static void getComplexAttributes(XSComplexType xsComplexType) {
    Collection<? extends XSAttributeUse> c = xsComplexType.getAttributeUses();
    Iterator<? extends XSAttributeUse> i = c.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
       // i.next is attributeUse
       XSAttributeUse attUse = i.next();
       System.out.println("Attributes for CoplexType:"+ xsComplexType.getName());

       parseAttribute(attUse);      
    }
}

// To Get attribute info

private static void parseAttribute(XSAttributeUse attUse) { 
    XSAttributeDecl attributeDecl = attUse.getDecl();
    System.out.println("Attribute Name:"+attributeDecl.getName());
    XSSimpleType xsAttributeType = attributeDecl.getType();
    System.out.println("Attribute Type: " + xsAttributeType.getName());
    if (attUse.isRequired())
        System.out.println("Use: Required");
    else
        System.out.println("Use: Optional");
    System.out.println("Fixed: " + attributeDecl.getFixedValue());
    System.out.println("Default: " + attributeDecl.getDefaultValue());
}
```